# Ban only all emojis (but not accents, break page, etc) in input, and limite the length of lines, with JS

Tags: javascript, regex, input, character, emoji

I have to be able to write only characters, with and without accents, in a maximum of 45 characters per line, and 3 lines maximum, thus preventing emojis, in a text area, with JS.
And it's got to start on typing or paste.

This is the working part that limits the characters, but it does not filter the emojis.

JS:

```
    $('#config_desc').on('keydown', function(e) {

       const newLine = /\r*\n/g;

       const value = e.target.value;

       const newLines = (value.match(newLine) || []).length;

       const lines = value.split(newLine);

       //enter
       if (e.keyCode === 13 && lines.length >= e.target.rows) {
         e.preventDefault();
         return;
       }

       const lineNo = value.substr(0, e.target.selectionStart).split(newLine).length - 1;

       //backspace
       if (e.keyCode === 8 && ~value.charAt(e.target.selectionStart - 1).search(newLine)) {
         if (lines[lineNo].length + lines[lineNo - 1].length <= e.target.cols) return;

         e.preventDefault();
         return;
       }

       //del
       if (e.keyCode === 46 && ~value.charAt(e.target.selectionStart).search(newLine)) {
         if (lines[lineNo].length + lines[lineNo + 1].length <= e.target.cols) return;

         e.preventDefault();
         return;
       }

       if (e.key.length > 1) return;

       if (value.length < e.target.cols) return;

       if (lines[lineNo].length > e.target.cols - 1) {
         if (lines.length < e.target.rows) {
           const col = (e.target.selectionStart - newLines) / lines.length;
           let p1 = value.substr(0, e.target.selectionStart);
           if (col === e.target.cols) {
             p1 += '\r\n' + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
           } else {
             p1 += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) + '\r\n';
           }

           e.target.value = p1 + value.substr(e.target.selectionStart, value.length);
           e.target.selectionStart = p1.length - 1;
           e.target.selectionEnd = p1.length - 1;
         }

         e.preventDefault();
         return;
       }
    });
```

HTML:

```
 <textarea cols="50" rows="3" class="form-control" maxlength="150" id="config_desc" name="config_desc"></textarea>
```

When I add this regex to ban the emoji, it's impossible to add break line etc.

`value.replace(/[^ -\u2122]+ +| *[^ -\u2122]+/ug,'')`

Comment: That strict 45x3 approach will only lead to more problems, i.e. [combining characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character), [different newline sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation) and [glyphs of varying width](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface#Proportion). Plus you don't seem to understand your own (redundant) regex to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should rather make a whitelist: `value.replace(/[^\n\u0020-\u007F\u00A0-\u024F]/ug,'')`. Add whatever ranges you want to allow to the brackets. Currently I allow Basic Latin + 2 Extensions, excluding control characters except newline. You might want to consult [a unicode table](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl) to find out what ranges you can permit.